# Transform() div not working correctly on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created the page in wordpress, it loads each section one at a time on mousewheel event, on mousewheel event the transform property working fine.

But when i bind the click event for transform then at every click it tranform the div at the bottom of screen and then it goes to the section.

Please see this link : [Click Here](http://77.104.146.92/~creati82)

When you will click on the Testimonials from top right menu bar then it goes at the bottom of screen and then move up-word on the testimonial section.

I am using the below code on click :

```
jQuery( window ).on( "load", function($) {

        //go to specific slider on menu click
        var item = document.getElementsByClassName("scroll-custom-js");
          jQuery.each( item, function( i, val ) {

             this.addEventListener("click",function(e){

                 var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                 jQuery('.scroll-custom-js').removeClass('arrow-custom');
                 jQuery(this).addClass('arrow-custom');
                 gotoSlide(link);

               });
          });
 });

 var gotoSlide = function () {

     document.querySelector(sliderElement).style.transform = 'translate3d(0, ' + -(currentSlide - 1) * 100 + '%,0)';

     document.querySelector(sliderElement).style.transition = 'transform 1000ms ease 0s';

  });
```

In jQuery :

```
jQuery('a.scroll-custom-js').click(function(e){
                var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                jQuery('.scroll-custom-js').removeClass('arrow-custom');
                 jQuery(this).addClass('arrow-custom');
                 e.preventDefault();
                 var move_slides = jQuery(link).attr('data-slider-index');
                 move_slides = move_slides - 1;


                 jQuery('.slides_custom').css({
                     transform: 'translate3d(0, ' + -(move_slides) * 100 + '%,0)',
                });
          });
```

Comment: why are you initiating the click event in a loop?

Comment: because i need to bind click event on every class scroll-custom-js. If you will use in jquery then it will work with single class name scroll-custom-js, no need to bind in loop.

Comment: so why aren't you using jquery?

Comment: I have also use in the jQuery , but still the problem exist. Please see the above question i have paste the code for jQuery also.

Comment: Why is `goToSlide()` in a variable and not a function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @madalinivascu , Thanks for your reply, as per your suggestion i have use the unbind and its resolve my issue. Thanks :)

Comment: Please post this as an answer to the question instead of a comment.  This will help others who are searching with similar issues know that this post could have value..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unbind()` to remove any click event that is bind to that div

```
jQuery('a.scroll-custom-js').unbind('click').click(function(e){
```

Comment: i have already use this , but still not working , please look the above question again in jquery section.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so i can test on it?

Comment: sorry @madalinivascu , i can't create jsfddle link, because it working fine if you will create on click transform , but not working correctly in worpress. And also unable to remove all the event on link.

Comment: try `jQuery('a.scroll-custom-js').unbind('click').click(function(e){` to remove any click event that is bind to that div

Comment: @dineshkashera glad to have helped